# How do I use a variable from one function in another?

Tags: swift

I was wondering how one might use a variable from one function in another? (I just can't seem to get my head around the documentation on this and Structs don't seem to be working for me)

Basically I have a function that removes some characters and then returns a quote/sentence with the characters redacted (/n)&(/) however I want to put the value that that function returns into my tweet sheet / share function. But I just can't seem to get it to work:

This is My Remove Characters Function:

```
var cachedQuote: String = interestingQuoteLabel.text!
    func removeSomeChars(a: String) -> String {
        var cachedQuote: String = ""
        for character in a {
            if character != "\"" && character != "\n" {
                cachedQuote += String(character)
            }
        }
        return cachedQuote
    }
```

and then I try to insert this into a Share Function but it doesn't work:

```
 @IBAction func shareButton(sender: UIButton) {

        var myShare = "Hi + \(sharedQuote) "
        let activityVC:UIActivityViewController =     UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Any ideas/Help would be appreciated,

I think I would have to declare an instance/global variable but that never works for some reason? Maybe I'm doing it differently.

Comment: Where is your `removeSomeChars` function? Is it standalone, or is it in a an object? Where is `sharedQuote`. Is it in the global namespace or an instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by declaring the variable at the beginning of my class

So it looked a little something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var myVar : String = ""

 @IBAction func showInterestingVar() {
         myVar = varButtonLabel.text! }

@IBAction func printVar() {
        println( myVar )  }

 }

// Note - Be sure not to redefine the Variable on the second instance, i.e) reference it like myVar = "2" instead of var myVar = "2" //
```

Hope this helps anyone else with this problem - Above what I did is I declared a Global Variable, Now in my case for my app this was needed, However it's often better coding practice to not only use Global Variables where needed, try encapsulating in structs or other methods before trying a Global Variable. Thanks to all that answered

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the return-value of your function and pass your `cachedQuote` to it:

```
func removeSomeChars(yourString:String) -> String {
    //Create set of characters you dont want.
    var charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\"\n")
    //Separate your string to remove them
    var cleanStringAsArray = yourString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet)
    //put the strings together
    var realString = join("", cleanStringAsArray)
    return realString
}

@IBAction func shareButton(sender: UIButton) {
    //Call the removeSomeChars method and put the value inside the cleanQuote variable
    var cleanQuote = removeSomeChars(cachedQuote)
    var myShare = "Hi + \(cleanQuote) "
    let activityVC:UIActivityViewController =     UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

As you see here, I've edited your `removeSomeChars` method. Because you've made it a bit to complicated. You can just set a `NSCharset` of chars you don't want inside a string and remove them by splitting the string into multiple strings and join them together. That way you can just add another char if you want really easy.

Comment: Appreciate the help, But i get the same error of 'Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction ) Any ideas?

Comment: Well have you connected an UIButton with the IBAction?

Comment: I think I have - `@IBAction func shareButton(sender: UIButton) {`

Comment: Basically I need to call the variable I create in the first `@IBAction` which is `realString` into the second @IBAction in order to share it, I still haven't figured this out - Any ideas?

Comment: In Addition to this I tried encapsulating in a struct - But to no avail,![See Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9c4593wyestywv/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-14%20at%2014.40.18.png?dl=0).